# why cocos2d-x use multi thread load sprite from servers is black

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, pthreads

I use 'pthread' to create a new thread. It load sprite from  server. But, the sprite is black color!

```
class Test: public CCLayer
{
public:
    Test();
    ~Test();
    virtual bool init();
    ...
private:
    pthread_t _tid;
    static void* _loadSprite(void*);
    void _doSth();
    CCSprite* _loadSpriteFromServer(); // load sprite from server.
};

void* Test::_loadSprite(void* param)
{
    Test* pThis = (Test*)param;
    pThis->_doSth();
    return NULL;
}
bool Test::init()
{
    pthread_create(&_tid, NULL, _loadSprite, this);
}
void Test::_doSth()
{
    CCSprite* pSprite = _loadSpriteFromServer();
    addSprite(pSprite); // the sprite is 'black'
}
```

who can help me, this bothered me for three days!

Answer (score 2):

You can't just thread code that needs to access OpenGL. In this case: creating the sprite, more specifically creating the sprite's texture. This needs to be done on the same thread as the OpenGL context, which is usually the main thread.

You can thread loading the image and saving it on the device, but you have to move creating the sprite to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class that supports server side/remote sprites in cocos2d-x v3

[RemoteSprite](https://developerhuddle.wordpress.com/2015/02/22/remotesprite-sprite-extension-to-support-server-hosted-graphics-cocos2d-x-c/)